# SerialPort.Read() always TimeoutException

Tags: vb.net, serial-port

This is the code I have a problem on.

In my form load, I got this:

```
Dim port as new Ports.SerialPort("MyPort", 100000)
port.DataBits = 8
port.StopBits = Ports.StopBits.One
port.Parity = Ports.Parity.None
port.Open()
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200)
```

Then in my button1.Click event, I got this:

```
Try
        If port.IsOpen Then
            Dim inStream(80) As Byte
            port.Read(inStream, 0, 80)
            Dim returndata As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(inStream, 0, 80)
            returndata = returndata.Replace(Chr(2), "A")
            returndata = returndata.Replace(Chr(3), "B")
            msg("Data from Server : " + returndata)
            Dim data As String
            data = Write(TextBox2.Text, TextBox2.Text.Substring(0, 4))
            Dim outStream As Byte() = _
            System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(STX & data & ETX)          '("Message from Client$")
            ashsp.Write(outStream, 0, outStream.Length)

        End If
Catch ex As Exception
End try
```

The problem here now is when I click button1, I got a TimeoutException when it hits `port.Read(inStream, 0, 80)`.

Comment: Looks like a basic causality violation.  You normally *first* write something, *then* read the response.  That button click isn't going to force the device to send anything of course.  Never ignore the return value of Read().   Not setting the Handshake property is another very basic reason why you don't get anything back from the device.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there are exactly 80 bytes to read?  You could use the BytesToRead property to dynamically check how many bytes are available.  Or if you are receiving only text on the serial port you could use the ReadExisting() method which puts all available bytes into a string object.